# Why do aggregation functions work without Group By?

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Consider a table called `Employee` with only the columns `Employee_ID` and `Salary`. Clearly

```sql
Select Max(Salary) from Employee;
```

works and returns exactly one row.

But why does this work? My points of confusion are as follows.

1. `Max` clearly isn't a window function; It's an aggregation function.
2. This can't be like `Pivot`, where unstated columns are put inside an implicit `Group By`, because `Select Max(Salary) From Employee Group By Employee_ID` would return one row per `Employee_ID`.
3. Every bit of documentation that I can find about aggregation functions has an explicit `Group By`.

Comment: A `GROUP BY` is only required when you have non-aggregated columns as well. Notice the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) states *"often used with the GROUP BY clause"* **not** 'must be used'.

Comment: *"Every bit of documentation that I can find about aggregation functions has an explicit `Group By`."* What documentation did you read? The [first example for `MAX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#a-simple-example) has no `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @ThomA I was reading the documentation for aggregation functions rather than `MAX` itself. I didn't notice anything about how they behave without `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @J.Mini you're asking about GROUP BY and the SELECT command, not the aggregation functions that process the result of GROUP BY. There's no reason to describe GROUP BY or SELECT in the function docs. If you check SELECT you'll see that GROUP BY is optional.

Comment: And what column(s) would you want to put in your group by clause here?

Comment: *"I was reading the documentation for aggregation functions rather than MAX itself."* `MAX` *is* an aggregate function though, and the Aggregate Functions documentation (that I linked earlier) doesn't have any examples and states "often" not "must". Can you link the documentation you read where it says it *must* be included? As the documentation for SQL Server is open source, it might be that someone could submit a correction to the document, *if* it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query `SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee` works without an explicit `GROUP BY` clause because it is an example of an aggregate query without any grouping specified. In such cases, the aggregate function operates on the entire result set, treating it as a single group.

You are correct that `MAX` is an aggregation function, not a window function that performs calculations on a set of rows and returns a single value as the result.

Unlike the `PIVOT` operation, which involves transforming rows into columns based on specific grouping criteria, the query `SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee` does not involve any grouping. It simply calculates the maximum value of the `Salary` column across all rows in the table.

According to Itzik Ben-Gan in his book [T-SQL fundamentals](https://itziktsql.com/t-sql-fund-4th-edition-1) (a book that I really enjoyed), when using aggregation functions, you would need to include a `GROUP BY` clause to specify the grouping criteria. However, if you omit the `GROUP BY` clause, the aggregation function operates on the entire result set as a single group. This behavior is specified by the SQL standard and allows you to perform aggregate calculations without explicitly grouping the data.

In the case of the query `SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee`, it calculates the maximum salary value across all employees and returns a single row with that value.